# Export animated mesh for Unreal Engine 4

Tags: animation, export, displacement, .fbx, unreal-engine

is it possible to export an animated mesh, such as a displaced sphere with animated texture coordinates, as fbx and import it to unreal engine?

Comment: Have you tried alembic already? Should work: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/WorkingWithContent/Importing/AlembicImporter/index.html